# math domain error in scipy.optimize python

Tags: python, scipy

I have a code to maximize the sum of log-likelihood of 61 week's weekly data, with the input data ignored here. 
The math error is on this line: 
`x=x+(math.log(incre[i]))*(numb[i])`. However, incre is a list of the difference of the CDF of a gamma weibull distribution. Basically incre[i]=F[i]-F[i-1] so it is for sure positive. The initial p0 yields the fine result, but when I tried the optimizer it always return math domain or math range error.
Also, sometimes I get math range error for `exp(bs*adjsale[i]+bx*adjchristmas[i]+ba*aba[i]))`. Removing the *exp and put a "+" solves this issue, and since exp here is only to make the latter part positive it isn't really necessary, but the log issue is still present.

I just got myself a little familiar with scipy so I am not sure where is the issue. I've tried different methods with no avail. There are actually no upper bounds for variables but I wanted to make it easier.

```
import scipy
from scipy import stats
from scipy.optimize import minimize
import math
from math import exp
import numpy as np
import pdb
import random
num=[3344,501,235,574,241,160  ,426  ,458  ,374  ,167,  106 ,  75   ,62 ,  67 ,  75 ,  72 , 102,  207  , 57   ,43  , 60, 59,   46,   40 , 135 ,  47 ,  43,   42, 43,   40 ,  29 , 397 , 208 ,  64 ,  46 ,  37 ,  39 ,  47 , 120 ,  55,   50 ,  40 ,  32 ,  44 ,  48,   56 ,  60 ,  52 ,  42 ,  50 ,  58 , 422 , 171 , 253 ,  97 , 187, 115 ,  72 ,  63 , 416 , 324,88405]
sale=[0,0,0,5,0,0,5,7,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,0,0,0,0,0,8,7,0,0,0,0,0,4,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,5,0,6,0,4,1,0,0,7,6]
time=[]
for i in range(1,62):
    time.append(i)
christmas=[0,0,0,0,0,0,5/7,1,4/7,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,0,1,6/7]
ab=[]
for i in range(51):
    ab.append(0)

def adjsale (sale,rs,ass):
    adjs=[]
    for i in range(61):
        adjs.append((stats.gamma.cdf((i+1),a=rs,scale=ass))*sale[i])
    return adjs

def adjchristmas(christmas,rs,ass):
    adjsc=[]
    for i in range(61):
        adjsc.append((stats.gamma.cdf((i+1),a=rs,scale=ass))*christmas[i])
    return adjsc

def aba(r2,a2):
    global ab
    ab.append((1-stats.gamma.cdf(4/7,a=r2,scale=a2))*4/7)
    for i in range(10):
        ab.append(1-stats.gamma.cdf(4/7+i+1, a=r2, scale=a2))
    return ab

def bt(time,c, bs,bx,ba,adjsale,adjchristmas,aba):
    newt=[1**c*math.exp(0)]
    for i in range(1,61):
        newt.append(newt[i-1]+((i+1)**c-i**c)*exp(bs*adjsale[i]+bx*adjchristmas[i]+ba*aba[i]))
    return newt

def ft(newt,r,a):
    cdft=[]
    for i in range (61):
        cdft.append(1-(a/(a+newt[i]))**r)
    return cdft

def increment (cdft):
    incre=[cdft[0]]
    for i in range (60):
        incre.append(cdft[i+1]-cdft[i])
    incre.append(1-cdft[60])
    return incre

def ll(numb, incre):
    x=0
    for i in range (62):
        x=x+(math.log(incre[i]))*(numb[i])
    return x

#parameters sequence: r, a, c, rs, as, rab, aab, bs, ba, bx
def objective(ps):
    global ll,adjsale,adjchristmas,aba,bt,ft,increment,ll, sale,time,christmas,num
    return -1*(ll(num,increment(ft(bt(time,ps[2],ps[7], ps[9], ps[8],adjsale(sale,ps[3],ps[4]),
  adjchristmas(christmas,ps[3],ps[4]),aba(ps[5],ps[6])),ps[0],ps[1]))))

ps0=[1,1,0.3,1,1,1,1,1,1,1]

b=(0.000001,111111)
c=(0.000001, 0.56)
bnds=(b,b,c,b,b,b,b,b,b,b)
solution=minimize(objective, ps0, method="Powell", bounds=bnds)
```

Comment: `math.log` raises this error if its argument is 0 or less.  You need to figure out why, or when, that is happening.  `math.exp` raises the range error if its argument is too large.  A quick test indicates that's between 700 and 800.

Comment: I know that log cannot take nonpositive arguments, but I think the way I write the functions make it always positive. Is it possible that a really small number will be treated as 0?

Comment: Not that it has anything to do with the error, but there's no point in defining functions like `ll` as `global`.  You aren't modifying those functions in the `objective` function.

Comment: It's hard to tell just looking at the code, what values `incre[i]` takes.  Is your code copy-n-paste runnable?  Not that it helps if that has 0 values, but did you know that `np.log` accepts an array?  I'm guessing that `ll` can be rewritten as `return np.sum(np.log(incre)*numb)`

Comment: It wasn't runnable but I've just added the data so it should be now. The reason I used math instead of np is that I saw somewhere that the array type may be messed up with other functions. It is probably not the best way to write these functions but it is a bit more straight forward /easier for me..(conceptually)

Comment: If I add a `print(incre)` to `ll`, the one that causes the error is mostly negative.  It's the 4th call to `optimize`.  If I replace it with the `np.log` version, I get a `RuntimeWarning: invalid value encountered in log` but it continues.

Comment: At the start of the run I get ` RuntimeWarning: Method Powell cannot handle constraints nor bounds.`

Comment: If I remove the `method` parameter (letting it choose) it runs with some warnings.  The `incre` input stabilizes to `[1e-11,0,0...,.999...]`,that is the `cdft` differences are 0.  The solution is 623692.674996247 and `array([1. , 1. , 0.3, 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. , 1. ])`

Comment: That's very helpful. Thanks! I'll look more closely.